# How to recompose Jetpack Compose UI after data change in Cloud Firestore database?

Tags: android, firebase, android-jetpack-compose

After data change in Cloud Firestore database, such as new item, or item's *read* value the Jetpack Compose UI won't recompose, even though i provided list as *mutableState*.

*Getting the items from Firebase (viewModel)*

```
private val _booksFromFB = mutableStateOf(listOf<BookFB>())
val booksFromFB = _booksFromFB

init {
    getBooksFromFB()
}

fun getBooksFromFB() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _isLoading.value = true
        _booksFromFB.value = repository.getBooksFromFB().data!!

        if (_booksFromFB.value.isNotEmpty())
            _isLoading.value = false
    }
}
```

*Getting the items from Firebase (repository)*

```
override suspend fun getBooksFromFB(): Resource<List<BookFB>> {
    return try {
        Resource.Loading(true)

        val response = queryBook.get().await().documents.map { documentSnapshot ->
            documentSnapshot.toObject(BookFB::class.java)!!
        }
        if (response.isNotEmpty())
            Resource.Loading(false)
        Resource.Success(response)
        
    } catch (exception: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
        Resource.Error(exception.message.toString())
    }
}
```

*Getting the list and use it in UI (in LazyColumn)*

```
 val userBooks = viewModel.booksFromFB.value.filter {
    it.userId == currentUser?.uid.toString()
}
```

*Further usage of the userBooks (LazyColum included)*

```
 CurrentlyReadingSection(
       context = context,
       navController = navController,
       userBooks = userBooks.filter { it.read == false },
       commonViewModel = commonViewModel
 )
```

*CurrentlyReadingSection*

```
LazyRow() {
        items(userBooks) { book ->
            BookRow(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
                onItemClicked = { }
            ) {
                val isExpanded = remember {
                    mutableStateOf(false)
                }

                val isRead = rememberSaveable {
                    mutableStateOf(false)
                }

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(AppColors.mBackgroundSec),
                    contentAlignment = BottomCenter
                ) {

                    Row {

                        AnimatedVisibility(visible = isExpanded.value) {
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxSize()
                                    .clickable {
                                        isExpanded.value = !isExpanded.value
                                    },
                                contentAlignment = Center
                            ) {
                                Column(
                                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                                ) {
                                    MyButton(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .fillMaxWidth(0.7f)
                                            .fillMaxHeight(0.2f)
                                            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)),
                                        text = "READ",
                                        fontSize = 12,
                                        contentPadding = 8
                                    ) {
                                        isRead.value = !isRead.value
                                        isExpanded.value = !isExpanded.value
                                        viewModel.updateBook(context = context, book = book, isRead = isRead.value)
                                    }
                                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))

                                    MyButton(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .fillMaxWidth(0.7f)
                                            .fillMaxHeight(0.24f)
                                            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)),
                                        text = "RATE",
                                        fontSize = 12,
                                        contentPadding = 8
                                    ) {
                                        commonViewModel.currentBook.value = book
                                        navController.navigate(Screen.Rate.route)
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                        }

                        AsyncImage(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
                                .clickable { isExpanded.value = !isExpanded.value },
                            model = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
                                .data(
                                    if (isValid(book.image))
                                        book.image
                                    else
                                        com.example.read.R.drawable.imagenotfound
                                )
                                .crossfade(true)
                                .build(),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
                            contentDescription = "Book image"
                        )
                    }

                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .fillMaxHeight(0.1f)
                            .background(if (book.read!!) AppColors.mGreen else AppColors.mRed)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

*BookRow*

```
@Composable
fun BookRow(
     modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
     book: BookFB = BookFB(),
     category: MyCategory = MyCategory("", ""),
     shapeDp: Int = 12,
     heightSize: Int = 170,
     widthSize: Int = 120,
     isForYou: Boolean = false,
     isYourCollection: Boolean = false,
     onItemClicked: () -> Unit = {},
     content: @Composable() () -> Unit,
) {

Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    modifier = if (isYourCollection) Modifier.widthIn(max = widthSize.dp) else Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
) {
    Surface(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(shapeDp.dp),
        elevation = 4.dp,
        modifier = modifier.border(2.dp, color = Color.Black, shape = RoundedCornerShape(shapeDp.dp))
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    onItemClicked()
                }
                .height(heightSize.dp)
                .width(widthSize.dp)
                .background(AppColors.mBackgroundSec))
        {
            content()
        }
    }

    if (isYourCollection) {

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp),
                text = book.title.toString(),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                color = AppColors.mTextWhite,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                maxLines = 3,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Clip
            )

    }

    if (isForYou) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp),
            text = category.name,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
            fontSize = 18.sp,
            color = AppColors.mTextWhite,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            maxLines = 3,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Clip
        )
    }
}
```

}

*Progress Bar in Home Screen*

```
 if (viewModel.isLoading.value) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                CircularProgressIndicator(color = AppColors.mMain)
            }
        } else {
            content..
        }
```

Comment: Please also show the code related to the LazyColumn.

Comment: @AlexMamo I've added the LazyColumn and BookRow.

Comment: @AlexMamo If you need more information, please check out the repo https://github.com/DEJA-1/READ, or ask me.

Comment: What exactly is going on when you load data? Do you have some kind of progress bar? If yes, is it still running every time?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, I do have a progress bar, I'll add the code to the question. However, it shows only after the first entry to the Home Screen, (after launching the app). After that, when I'm playing around in the application it doesn't show any more. I guess it's also the problem with recomposition

Comment: I have No idea what is this problem about

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot spot the issue here. What I think would help, is this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953). It's a working solution. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudFirestore/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251540/discussion-between-deja-and-alex-mamo).